# SVG path not displaying

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, choropleth

I'm trying to display an SVG of alabama's counties taken from [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Map_of_Alabama_highlighting_Autauga_County.svg). For some reason the paths seperating out the counties aren't displaying, just the red fill for the Autauga county. I'm using the following code to display the SVG. I've already tried setting `stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" fill="yellow"` on individual path elements to see if they would appear but without any success. Any idea what I need to do to make it display properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SVG Test</title>
        <script src="../site/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../site/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                d3.xml("alabama_wikipedia.svg", "image/svg+xml", function(xml){
                    $("body").append(xml.documentElement);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the `clip-path` property of the `<g>`

Comment: @Kaiido, you should write up an answer with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the `clip-path` attribute of the `<g>`element